# Background location Services is not working on iOS 11.2.2

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I am using coreLocation services/Framework to get location update in the foreground and background states. My app works fine in these both cases. But it won't work when the user quits/terminated app forcefully in login state. When user app relaunches then the first problem Xcode will not print logger in debugger session. The second thing may be didUpdateLocations method couldn't work.

Following settings which I have done for my project. 
- I have checked in Location updates under capabilities section. 
- I have added always and when in usage description, when in usage description, location usage description, Required background modes in info.plist file.

[**Note:** I am using objective c language for project & Xcode 9.2 with iOS 11.2.2 latest version. My code was well working on iOS 10 but when I upgraded to 11.2.2 that is the latest version it is not working.] Could anybody help me to sort out this problem? Am I missing something?

**Code:** Here I am implemented my location tracking method. called it from two delegates methods - applicationDidBecomeActive & applicationDidEnterBackground.

```
- (void)startLocationTracking
{
    NSString *responeParam = @"";
    if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] == NO)
    {
        responeParam = @"Disabled location";
    }
    else
    {
        CLAuthorizationStatus authorizationStatus= [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];    
        if(authorizationStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied || authorizationStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted)
        {
            responeParam = @"Unauthorize location";
        }
        else
        {
            responeParam = @"Authorize location";
            CLLocationManager *locationManager = [LocationTracker sharedLocationManager];
            locationManager.delegate = self;
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
            locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
            if (SystemVersion > 9.2)
            {
                [locationManager setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:YES];
                locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false;
            }
            NSLog(@"location updating ");
            [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        }
    }
}
```

**In applicationDidEnterBackground also I have maintained bgTaskId**

```
-(UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier)beginNewBackgroundTask
{
    UIApplication* application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

   UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTaskId = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    if([application respondsToSelector:@selector(beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:)]){
        bgTaskId = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{

        }];
        if ( self.masterTaskId == UIBackgroundTaskInvalid )
        {
            self.masterTaskId = bgTaskId;
        }
        else
        {
            [self.bgTaskIdList addObject:@(bgTaskId)];
            [self endBackgroundTasks];
        }
    }

    return bgTaskId;
}
```

Comment: show me error please

Comment: Xcode will not print logger in debugger session. how could I show you the error? May be I am gettng  lat 0.0 and long 0.0

Comment: please see your code otherwise share project, if its demo project

Comment: If the user terminatesyour app then you won't get location updates since the app is no longer running. How are you relaunching the app? From Xcode or just by tapping the icon. If the latter, have you told Xcode to attach to the proces in order to get debug log messages?

Comment: @KhawarIslam Thanks, I have added the code. Just look into that and let me know any solution is there.

Comment: Thanks, @Paulw11 for the reply. While relaunching I am just tapping the icon. As you said, Xcode to attach to the process in order to get debug log messages, Could you please provide me steps to do this that will help to get me loggers.

Comment: @TejasRatunawar Sorry Man am working on Swift 4

Comment: From the Debug menu in Xcode select "Attach to process" or "Attach to process by pid/name".  However, it is simpler to relaunch the app from Xcode that to tap the icon and attach to it

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks. I have followed the steps and attached the process but still, logs are not showing on Navigator pane after relaunching the app.

Comment: @KhawarIslam That's fine. Anyway thanks.

Comment: Why not just relaunch the app from Xcode?

Comment: Guys in my case may be background location service has started but it looks like it won't gives me latitude and longitude. It's getting me 0.0000 what it means? what are the possibilities of getting such numbers? If my code is ok then it has to work.

Comment: @Paulw11 Yeah, I am using iPhone 6s device rather than using Xcode simulator. Is it matter?

Comment: It doesn't matter.  Where are you getting the 0,0 location?  In your `didUpdateLocations` delegate method?

Comment: I am not clear what you are actually asking anymore. Be aware though that if you call `startUpdatingLocation` when your app is already in the background you will only get updates for about 3 minutes unless you have significant location change monitoring on as well

Comment: I am reconstructing my statements - Yeah, I am getting at didUpdateLocations but I couldn't get the logs on the console. By looking at the code where I don't think 
I need any change required. I have added both authorization statements, So according to me, some another reason I am not getting the latitude and longitude desired so that I could not calculate arrival time. can we say apple kill my background location tracking process when the user quits the app? If it is so then is there anything apart from authorization which will not kill the background process. @Paulw11

Comment: Yeah right said @Paulw11 I have managed background taskId and it works fine in case of normal flow when user won't kill the app.